# Signing a Java SOAPheader using a X509 certificate

Tags: java, soap, x509, soapheader

I have been given a X509 certificate that I have to use to sign a Java soapheader. How would I go about doing this?

Basically I want to do what is in this example but using a external X509 Certificate

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0410__Web-Services-SOA/SignSOAPmessage.htm